# How can I manage memory better in a Swift ViewController with a tableview and SceneKit scenes for each cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory, instruments

So in my iOS Swift/Storyboards/UIKit app I have `GameViewController` that presents an `UpgradesViewController` like this:

```
@IBAction func upgradesButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        feedbackGeneratorSoft.impactOccurred()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let upgradesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UpgradesViewController") as? UpgradesViewController {
            
            upgradesViewController.delegate = self
            present(upgradesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

and that `UpgradesViewController` has a tableView in it that I access through an outlet like this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewOutlet: UITableView!
```

also the delegate looks like this for future reference:

```
    weak var delegate: UpgradeToGameProtocol?
```

Now here is where I'd like to better utilize memory and understand what's happening in my code. Each cell is a custom cell with a sceneView in this tableView and cell creation looks like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    var sceneCache = NSCache<NSString, SCNScene>()
    private func configureSceneView(cell: UpgradeTableViewCell, with scene: SCNScene) {
        cell.upgradeSceneViewOutlet.scene = scene
        cell.upgradeSceneViewOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.upgradeSceneViewOutlet.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        cell.upgradeSceneViewOutlet.allowsCameraControl = false
        scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = false
            node.castsShadow = false
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableviewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "upgradeCell", for: indexPath) as! UpgradeTableViewCell
        
        let sectionOffset = indexPath.section * 8
        let itemIndex = sectionOffset + indexPath.row
        
        let imageName = "\(UpgradeBrain.shared.vcUpgradesArray[itemIndex].image)"
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            if let cachedScene = self?.sceneCache.object(forKey: imageName as NSString) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.configureSceneView(cell: cell, with: cachedScene)
                }
            } else if let scene = try? SCNScene(named: imageName, inDirectory: nil, options: nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.sceneCache.setObject(scene, forKey: imageName as NSString)
                    self?.configureSceneView(cell: cell, with: scene)
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to load .usdz file")
            }
        }
        
        cell.upgradeName.text = upgradeBrain.vcUpgradesArray[itemIndex].name
        cell.amountLabel.text = addCommaToNumber(num: gameBrain.firebaseUpgrades[itemIndex].purchaseCost) + " Sats"
        cell.quantityLabel.text = "x\(self.fbUpgradesArray[itemIndex].quantityOwned)"
        cell.upgrabeBonusLabel.text = "+ " + addCommaToNumber(num: gameBrain.firebaseUpgrades[itemIndex].rateIncrease) + " Sats"
        cell.upgradeDescription.text = upgradeBrain.vcUpgradesArray[itemIndex].description
        cell.cellnumber = itemIndex
        cell.quantityOwned = upgradeBrain.vcUpgradesArray[itemIndex].quantityOwned
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

and I am having issues with managing memory. What's happening is when `GameViewController` loads I am using about ~215mb of memory, which is normal at this point. (`gameVC` has its own scenekit and spritekit scenes). When I tap the button to bring up my `UpgradesViewController` that is presented modally and scroll to the end of my tableView to load every usdz model in each cell's sceneView (24 total every time) the memory jumps up to about ~1.1gb being used. When I dismiss it the memory drops to about ~545mb being used. This is what `viewWillDisappear()` looks like in my `UpgradesViewController`:

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("viewWillDisappear Called()")
        sceneCache.removeAllObjects()
    }
```

Why isn't the memory usage going back down here on `viewWillDisappear()`? If I open `UpgradesViewController` again it jumps up to about ~1.3gb and once I dismiss again it droped to about ~775mb being used. Opening once more and scrolling bring it up to ~1.45gb being used and dismissing drops it to ~960mb used. You can keep doing this until you reach the memory limit and the app crashes.

It keeps increasing by ~200ish mb every time you open and dismiss the `UpgradesViewController`.

I've tried using Instruments to diagnose it but it reports no memory leak anywhere, and since I'm not very familiar with it I'm not sure where to go from there. Also both my phone and computer become very unresponsive when diagnosing with Instruments. (8th gen i5 and 8gb of ram with an iphone 13).

All of my delegates throughout the entire app are `weak` and I wasn't running into any issues with too much memory usage before when these sceneViews were actually ImageViews. (They would deallocate on dismissal.) Also I am always loading 24 different usdz models and the largest model being about ~4mb and the smallest being ~60kb, with most being ~1mb.

Does anyone know how I can either

A: Reduce memory usage from ~1gb when all models are loaded (should be like 25mb extra in raw file size)

or

B: Have the memory properly deallocate when the `UpgradesViewController` is dismissed?

EDIT:
Here is a picture of the memory graph slowly increasing each time I open and close the `UpgradesViewController`
[image: Here is a picture of]